# Docker how to create custom docker with multiple images in python

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have created a python file which uses multiple packages, for example, PyTorch, sklearn, etc.
Now I want to create a custom docker file that uses multiple images for each package I have used in my python file and run it in docker. I didn't understand much until now. Can someone help me with started code with

```
1. import pytorch image
2.import/install sklearn package 
3. run a python file in the environment.
```

Comment: you can use this image https://github.com/petronetto/docker-python-deep-learning
If you want to create your own dockerfile then you can get help from its dockerfile here. https://github.com/petronetto/docker-python-deep-learning/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get the question correctly or not, But the below docker file can be used to build docker python images. The file starts by 
- Importing one of the python officials gems
- Copy the project files to the docker image
- Install OS dependencies
- Install python packages listed in requirements.txt file.
- define the container command.

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim-stretch

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app


# Install client libs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        gcc \
        vim \
        locales \
        dos2unix \
    && pip install pip==9.0.1 \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    &&  pip install -r requirements.txt \
    &&  apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc \
    &&  apt-get clean \
    &&  rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base


CMD ["python", "my.py"]script
```